# bash: /usr/bin/lein: Permission denied

Tags: bash, permissions

The above error is given when I type lein into the command line in the home directory. For instance;

```
master@slave:~$ lein tutorial
bash: /usr/bin/lein: Permission denied
```

I downloaded the lein script and placed it in my downlods folder then ran the following commands.

```
master@slave:~$ cd /home/master/Downloads
master@slave:~/Downloads$ sudo scp lein /usr/bin/
[sudo] password for master: 
master@slave:~/Downloads$ sudo chmod a+x lein
master@slave:~/Downloads$ ./lein
```

After which the installation started with;

```
Downloading Leiningen to /home/master/.lein/self-installs/leiningen-2.5.3-standalone.jar now...
```

and proceeded without errors.

My java version is;

java version "1.7.0_79"

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.6) (7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.14.04.1)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your `chmod` changed the permissions on the copy in `~/Downloads`.  You need to set the executable bit on the copy in `/usr/bin`.

Also the `./lein` is trying to run the file in `~/Downloads`.

Try it in this order:

```
sudo cp ~/Downloads/lein /usr/bin # note cp, not scp, there's no need to use scp
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/lein
lein
```

Assuming `lein` is a valid runnable file, this should work.

Comment: master@slave:/usr/bin$ chmod a+x lein -is what I needed